# Apply bootstrap form styling to div elements without changing class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm building a screen with many form elements using the convention below; it saves me from adding `class='...'` to every input, button, and select box.

```
.formDiv button {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius:3px;
}

.formDiv input {
  font-family: verdana;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  width: 110px;
}
```

Now I want to use bootstrap; I've got everything configured; confirmed it's working.
Is it possible to apply bootstrap3 styling without adding `class='some-bs-style'` to each form element? Ideally, I want to do something like this:

```
.myDiv input {
   //use bs3 input styling
}

.myDiv select {
   //use bs3 select styling
}
```

I see bootstrap uses `form-control`, so I tried setting that on the parent div using:

`<div id='#formdiv' class='form-control'>`

..but it did not work; I suck at css, so no surprise there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the rules from **form-control** and just apply the rules to input and select if you want to use it automatically for your **formdiv** class:

```
.formdiv input, select {
RULES FROM FORM CONTROL
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/nukec/6J8mT/4/)

**Updated DEMO** + CSS is here: http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.css

Copying is necessary because you cannot inherit rules from other classes. Therefore if you want to avoid applying form-control style to each input and select, you have to use approach above. But this is still faster than putting "form-control" to each input in each form.

Comment: damn, was afraid of that; is copying the only option? Also, the input controls are not immediate children of the parent div, they're just in the div at different locations, does that matter?

Comment: I fixed on focus for input and select, so take the latest version.